# Uploading an image from iOS to PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, http, post

I've been working on uploading an UIImage to an webserver. The problem is, that the image never appears on the Server. A normal POST from an HTML file works. I think it's an issue in my objective-c code.

Here is my objective-c code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(delegate.dataBean.image);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@test.php", delegate.dataBean.hosterURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image Return String: %@", returnString]);
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo $file;
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: print_r($_FILES) what does that show

Comment: it shows an empty array:


Array
(
)

Comment: $_FILES should be defined by default. But if there is an upload, it shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Now i've solved it by myself =)

I forgot the backslashes in the body.

Here is the right body:

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```