# Browse all pdf and text files in the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

browse file in iphone I'm developing an iPhone app in which I have to upload the PDF and text files on server from iPhone. Please guide me can i browse all pdf files stored in iPhone into my application?

Comment: You can't browse your iphone because file system is closed. Only your application can browse its own filesystem.You can store pdf and text file into your document directory or Library. Read NSFileManager from apple documentation. You can send data of the desired file in HTTP Post and put content-type as "text/pdf" for PDF file

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to Monitor(Browse) the Files in IOS. Apple does not Approve this type of applications. And also iPhone/iPad we can't access the Other Application Data's. As per your point The PDF must be located in Other iOS Application. We can't Browse the Files Except Bundles and Documents folder.

Only way you can Upload file to Server and Make browser list Using Tableview.

The following are the possible ways to do this.

1. FTP UPLOAD:
   We can Upload Documents to FTP Server and Download Via FTP in iOS.
   In This. Upload and Download we neet to use Authentication policy.
   [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)
   [Upload things to a FTP in Objective-C iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483577/upload-things-to-a-ftp-in-objective-c-ios)
2. Server Upload.
   We can Upload File to Server(Php,ASP.net,ect). The download is Ordinary method.
   [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413846/uploading-an-image-from-ios-to-php)
   [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711481/sending-file-from-ios-to-php-using-post)

Comment: Dear uploading is not an issue for me. I was looking for a code to browse all pdf files exist in my phone.

Comment: We can't do this. Because Apple not Allowed to Access files.

Answer (score 0):

You app runs in a Sandbox environment. This means the app can only access files and directories within its own contents.

[More Information On File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)