# IMAGE UPLOAD TO SERVER IN iOS

Tags: ios, image-upload

In my project I have a requirement of uploading an image to the server.I have implemented the code below but due to some issues the image is not getting uploaded in the server. I am not getting any response from the server end. The API is working perfectly.I have checked it in postman it is working fine. I am posting the code below.

```
-(void)callProfilePictureUpdateServiceWithUserID:(NSString *)strUserID ImageData:(NSData*)imgData WithCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:urlService.absoluteURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSMutableData *body=[NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    // Set Image Data

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"avtar.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Set User ID.

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[strUserID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSOperationQueue *myQueue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:myQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) {
            handler(connectionError,YES,@"Connection error happen, please try again later.");
        }else{

        }
    }];
}
```

Any ideas what could be missing?

Comment: Does the server see your connection attempt?  (If so, what does its log say?)

Comment: Check "filename" with server.

Comment: 1. Check the `response`, cast to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and check the `statusCode` returned by the server. See [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for details 2. Use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to see the server request and response in detail.

Comment: WHY SHOUT IN ALL CAPS??

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot in SO about this. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728317/upload-image-to-the-php-server-from-ios) you can find more.

```
-(void)uploadImage
    {       
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

        NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourUploadImageURl.php?intid=%@",1];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", 1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if you could mention the problem which I was facing while executing the code which i posted.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413846/uploading-an-image-from-ios-to-php) may be duplicate question.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```